# Error downloading celebA dataset using torchvision

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

Using the torchvision module datasets, I can't download the celebA image dataset.
I am pretty sure that I am doing everything right.

```
dataset = datasets.CelebA(
    root='../datasets/celebA/train_images',
    split='train',
    target_type='identity',
    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]),
    download=True)
```

The error:

```
BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

It is a known issue that has been already reported in [#1920](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1920), and it seems it was fixed in [#4109](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/4109) but the commit is not yet included in a stable release.

In the meanwhile you can do the following:

- Look at the source code of [datasets.CelebA](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/_modules/torchvision/datasets/celeba.html), search for `file_list` and take note of the files in it.
- Download those files from [here](http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/projects/CelebA.html), and copy the files in a new directory called `celeba`
- Unzip `img_align_celeba.zip` in the same directory

Finally call `datasets.CelebA()` with `download=False`.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me the file structure it should be? Here is mine and it doesn't seem to work:

```{root_dir}/celeba/
img_align_celeba (folder)
list_attr_celeba.txt
list_bbox_celeba.txt
list_eval_partition.txt
list_landmarks_align_celeba.txt
```

Comment: What error do you get?